# How i can get items from a model that are not used in ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model (`ModelA`) with a `ManyToManyField` linking to another model (`ModelB`) like this:

```
class ModelA (models.Model):
    field = models.ManyToManyField('ModelB',blank=True )

class ModelB (models.Model):
    ....
```

How can I get all objects form `ModelB` that are not used in `ManyToManyField` relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter all the objects of `ModelB` where `ModelA` is `None`:

```
queryset = ModelB.objects.filter(modela=None)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for , Thank you

Answer (score -1):

when we use ManyToManyField a third table is automatically created after migration...
which will be 'yourappnameModelAModelB' use this table name in your query.... and dont forget to replace yourappname mentioned with table name